# KDE4 widgets in Qt Designer / Qt Creator / KDevelop

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma

Long time ago, I used KDevelop 3 to create a simple GUI application for KDE 3 in Linux.
And I remember that I was using built-in GUI Builder for creating user interface.

The question is:

Is there possible nowadays to use KDE **4** widgets (instead of Qt 4 ones) in any of modern IDEs (like, for example, Qt Creator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, sure you can. And note that there is already KF5(KDE5) and Qt5. Also note that you will need QtCreator/QtDesigner build with Qt4 to use KDE4 widgets